# (Libgdx && PhysicsEditor) 2 bodies that rotate around different origin points, used for different detections that I need to always be overlapping

Tags: math, libgdx

I'm using a Physics Editor body for collision detection, and the b2body for general positioning and rotation due to physics editors origin point. The box2D body has the origin at its centre while the Physics Editor body has its origin at the bottom left. The origin point cannot be changed for either of them, and they need to always be directly on top of each other. Due to the difference in origin point setting the PE body to the Box2D body's position results in the PE body being in the top left corner of the Box2D body. They need to be overlapping. I need a mathematical formula to set PE body's transform to. I.E if they had the same origin point the code would look like this: `PEBody.setTransform(box2DBody.getPosition.x, box2DBody.getPosition.y, box2DBody.getAngle();` but due to differing origin points (again, that I cannot change) that code results in this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeXB6nrGePg

Since I'm not that good at math I'm not entirely sure but I think this has something to do with trigonometry, what I'm looking for is something like this: `PEBody.setTransform(box2DBody.getPosition.x - *some formula based on box2DBody.getAngle()*, box2DBody.getPosition.y - *some formula based on box2DBody.getAngle()*, box2DBody.getAngle();`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following image is where theta (the angle of rotation) is zero,

[image: theta = 0]

then the following line of code should work:

`PEBody.setTransform(
box2DBody.getPosition.x + box2DBody.getWidth() * 0.5 * cos(box2DBody.getAngle()) + box2DBody.getHeight() * 0.5 * sin(box2DBody.getAngle()),
box2DBody.getPosition.y + box2DBody.getHeight() * 0.5 * cos(box2DBody.getAngle()) + box2DBody.getWidth() * 0.5 * sin(box2DBody.getAngle()), box2DBody.getAngle()`

Replace `.getWidth()` and `.getHeight()` with whatever functions you use to get the body's width and height, and likewise for `sin()` and `cos()`.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for the reply but this didn't seem to work, I tried re-working it and trying everything I could think of but nothing really got close.

Comment: OK, what *did* it do?

Comment: It made Pe body elipse around box2dbody, I managed to tweak it and I got something pretty close to workingt. The tweaked version looks like this: `        PEBody.setTransform(
                b2body.getPosition().x - (24 / SpaceSoccer.PPM) * (float) Math.cos(b2body.getAngle()),
                b2body.getPosition().y - (24 / SpaceSoccer.PPM) * (float) Math.sin(b2body.getAngle()), b2body.getAngle() - (float) Math.PI / 2);` 24 / SpaceSoccer.PPM is half the width (and height). It made PEBody align with box2D bofy in the y axis but not x-axis and keeps it stationary while rotating.